# How to put a name on the email sender?

Tags: symfony, swiftmailer

I'm trying to, when an email is sent within my Symfony2 application, to name the sender

```
Administrator <no-reply@app.com>
```

I've tried in the `parameters.ini` :

```
mailer_from      = {"no-reply@app.com : Administrator"}
```

It seems possible to do so because in SimpleMessage.php we do have :

```
  /**
   * Set the sender of this message.
   * This does not override the From field, but it has a higher significance.
   * @param string $sender
   * @param string $name optional
   * @return Swift_Mime_SimpleMessage
   */
  public function setSender($address, $name = null)
  {
    if (!is_array($address) && isset($name))
    {
      $address = array($address => $name);
    }

    if (!$this->_setHeaderFieldModel('Sender', (array) $address))
    {
      $this->getHeaders()->addMailboxHeader('Sender', (array) $address);
    }
    return $this;
  }
```

**All the things I tried in the `parameters.ini` failed. Do you have any idea of what i'm doing wrong please ?**

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
// Set a single From: address
$message->setFrom('your@address.tld');

// Set a From: address including a name
$message->setFrom(array('your@address.tld' => 'Your Name'));

// Set multiple From: addresses if multiple people wrote the email
$message->setFrom(array(
  'person1@example.org' => 'Sender One',
  'person2@example.org' => 'Sender Two'
));
```

Answer (score 3):

> It seems possible to do so because in SimpleMessage.php we do have

Well, it is possible to set a name, but there is nothing indicating you can set it using the configuration.

A quick dump of the available config for the `SwitfMailerBundle`  (`php app/console config:dump-reference SwiftmailerBundle`) will return:

```
Default configuration for "SwiftmailerBundle"
swiftmailer:          
    transport:            smtp 
    username:             ~ 
    password:             ~ 
    host:                 localhost 
    port:                 false 
    encryption:           ~ 
    auth_mode:            ~ 
    spool:                
        type:                 file 
        path:                 %kernel.cache_dir%/swiftmailer/spool 
    sender_address:       ~ 
    antiflood:            
        threshold:            99 
        sleep:                0 
    delivery_address:     ~ 
    disable_delivery:     ~ 
    logging:              true
```

As you can see, there is `sender_address` which is passed to the `ImpersonatePlugin.php`.

I'm not sure, you'll be able to set a name, but the standard way, rawly, is to use a string of that form:

"Administrator "

If it doesn't work, it probably means, that you'll some work, to write a real EmailManager.

SwiftMailerBundle is actually only an integration of the SwiftMailer library, which is, a library, and not a "Manager".

Comment: That's why i did, i wrote the EmailManager which gets the config i want in the parameters.ini. Thanks for the tip

Comment: Looks like there is an open PR for this config feature: https://github.com/symfony/SwiftmailerBundle/issues/94 +1